# Cannot close InAppBrowser on iPhone, done button is missing when page is opened.

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

InAppBrowser missing the "Done" button that returns user to the app when using on iPhone. It is getting getting stuck on the webpage.

```
.directive("navigateTo", function($ionicGesture){

return{
  restrict: 'A',
  link:function($scope,$element,$attr)  {

var tapHandler = function(e) {
var inAppBrowser = window.open(encodeURI($attr.navigateTo),'_blank','location=no', 'toolbar=yes');
  };
var tapGesture =$ionicGesture.on('tap', tapHandler, $element);
$scope.on('$destroy', function(){
  $ionicGesture.off(tapGesture, 'tap', tapHandler);
     });
    }
  }
})
```

This is all the code for InAppBrowser. I call the navigateTo from one of the views in my app to open a link to a webpage.

Comment: what you mean by done button . I didn't get your point

Comment: If you have ever used InAppBrowser, when you open a webpage, if you have 'toolbar=yes' it displays a done button to return to the application.  http://www.telerik.com/sfimages/default-source/blogs/inappbrowser-workflow-png-png  see this link.

Comment: Solved:  InAppBrowser plugin is not currently supported on Ionic View.